# How to select everything NOT in a table from another table in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

So I have two tables :

**Table 1.**

```
ID  value value2
001     A    blue 
002     V     red
003     A    blue
004     V   green
005     X    blue
```

**Table 2.**

```
ID  value value2
001     A    blue 
004     V   green
```

All I would like to do is using a CTE (thats important given the nature of the data) , return the instances where the table2 ID's do not appear in table 1. Looking like:

**CTE Result**

```
ID  value  value2
002     V     red
003     A    blue
005     X    blue
```

So I'm expecting something like:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT ID, value,value2
FROM table1
),
t2 AS (
SELECT ID, value,value2
FROM table2
)
SELECT 
??????
```

I thought it would be some sort of join but I am struggling to do it this way properly.

Comment: you sentance and example don't match: `return the instances where the table2 ID's do not appear in table 1.` would be an empty set, as table2 id's (001, 004) are both in table1. Your `results` show the table1 values not in table2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The MINUS way:

Well not a CTE at all, but given your rows are "all the same" you could do a [MINUS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#minus-except):

```
SELECT id, value, value2 FROM table1
MINUS 
SELECT id, value, value2 FROM table2;
```

| ID | VALUE | VALUE2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 002 | V | red |
| 003 | A | blue |
| 005 | X | blue |

which in the context of using CTE's to prefetch/condition the data can be:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table1
), t2 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table2
)
SELECT id, value, value2 FROM table1
MINUS 
SELECT id, value, value2 FROM table2
```

now if your CTE's align the columns all the same that can be simplified to:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table1
), t2 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table2
)
SELECT * FROM table1
MINUS 
SELECT * FROM table2
```

### The LEFT JOIN way:

This can also be done with a LEFT JOIN (called a LEFT OUTER JOIN) by adding a WHERE IS NULL clause:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table1
), t2 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table2
)
SELECT t1.id, t1.value, t1.value2 
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id /* plus other clauses if you want those as well */
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

| ID | VALUE | VALUE2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 002 | V | red |
| 003 | A | blue |
| 005 | X | blue |

### What you asked for with words:

> return the instances where the table2 ID's do not appear in table 1.

expressed as a LEFT JOIN:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table1
), t2 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table2
)
SELECT t2.id, t2.value, t2.value2 
FROM table2 as t2
LEFT JOIN table1 as t1
    ON t1.id = t2.id /* plus other clauses if you want those as well */
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

gives no results:

because `001` & `004` are both in `table1`

this can also be expressed as a RIGHT JOIN:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table1
), t2 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table2
)
SELECT t2.id, t2.value, t2.value2 
FROM table1 as t1
RIGHT JOIN table2 as t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id /* plus other clauses if you want those as well */
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

which still returns no results.

### Funny to me aside on CTE's

I almost always use CTE's to input "fake data" for people's questions, thus to structure this question and "use your two CTE's" I had to nest my CTE's which is just really funny, but shows how to nest them, and how powerful they can be:

```
WITH table1(ID, value, value2) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('001', 'A', 'blue'),
        ('002', 'V', 'red'),
        ('003', 'A', 'blue'),
        ('004', 'V', 'green'),
        ('005', 'X', 'blue')
), table2(ID, value, value2) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('001', 'A', 'blue'),
        ('004', 'V', 'green')
), cte as(
  
    
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table1
), t2 AS (
  SELECT ID, value,value2
  FROM table2
)
SELECT t2.id, t2.value, t2.value2 
FROM table1 as t1
RIGHT JOIN table2 as t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id /* plus other clauses if you want those as well */
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
    
    
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```